# The generator of $K_0(C(\partial(]0,1[^2)))$ and $K_1(C(\partial(]0,1[^2)))$

Tags: c-star-algebras, k-theory, topological-k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $C=[0,1]^2 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and $\partial C$ the boundary of $C$.
I'm looking for the $K_0(C(\partial C))$ and $K_1(C(\partial C))$ and its generator.

Comment: The boundary of $C$ is homeomorphic to the unit circle $S^1$.  Does that help?

Comment: I think yes, because the $K_0(C(S^1)$ and $K_1(C(S^1)$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, so we can say that the $K_0(C(\partial C)$ and $K_1(C(\partial C)$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. But i need the generators of $K_0(C(S^1)$. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What do you know/what have you tried?

Comment: I put the morphism $\phi : C([0,1]^2)\rightarrow C(\partial C); f\mapsto f_{\mid \partial C}$ what induces the group morphism $K_0(C([0,1]^2))\rightarrow K_0(C(\partial C))$. But i Can not find the generators

Answer (score 1):

From the split exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow C_0(\mathbb R)\to C(S^1)\leftrightarrows\mathbb C\to 0,$$
we obtain split exact sequences in $K$-theory
$$0\to K_i(C_0(\mathbb R))\to K_i(C(S^1))\leftrightarrows K_i(\mathbb C)\to 0,$$
so that
$$K_i(C(S^1))=K_i(C_0(\mathbb R))\oplus K_i(\mathbb C)\cong\mathbb Z.$$
Now this tells us that $K_0(C(S^1))=K_0(\mathbb C)$ is generated by the class of identity function $z\mapsto 1$ in $C(S^1)$.

For the generator of $K_1(C(S^1))$, we first note that $K_1(C(S^1))=K_1(C_0(\mathbb R))\cong K_0(\mathbb C)$, where the last isomorphism is via the Bott map.  Since the Bott map applied to $1\in\mathbb C$ gives us the identity function $z\mapsto z\in C(S^1)$, this tells us that $K_1(C(S^1))$ is generated by the class of this function.